# How to use Directory.GetFiles to get only gif types (or any other type)?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to filter files by extension (in particular case ".gif") but `GetFiles` method for some reason does not find any files (even if there are definitely files of that type in the folder).

This code gives me list of all files.

```
private void displaylastanimatedgif()
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(animatedgifsdirectory);
            var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                          orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                          select f).First();
            if (myFile != null)
                pictureBoxImage(myFile.FullName);
            listBox1.Items.Add(outputfile);
        }
```

If I add filter to the `GetFiles()` like `Directory.GetFiles("*.gif")` I will get exception:

> Sequence contains no elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 versions of "GetFiles" method. 2 of which includes a filter option:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The version you were using accepts a "path". Not a filter.

- Option 1 [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) with two arguments:

  ```
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(animatedgifsdirectory, "*.gif");
  ```
- Option 2 [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx) instance method takes filter as single parameter:

  ```
  var directory = new DirectoryInfo(animatedgifsdirectory);
  var files = directory.GetFiles(animatedgifsdirectory, "*.gif");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [search pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload on `GetFiles`:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows", "*.gif");
```